# Slick - how to split population of test data into separate file

Tags: scala, slick, implicit

I have a working bit of code that generates my schema in slick

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult, StaticQuery => Q}

Database.forURL("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gopher_dev",
  driver = "org.postgresql.Driver",
  user = "unodishuser",
  password = "unodishpass"
) withSession {
  implicit session =>

    //drop and recreate public schema
    Q.updateNA("drop schema public cascade").execute
    Q.updateNA("create schema public").execute

    import Tables._
    //Make the tables
    (users.ddl ++ sessionData.ddl).create

    users ++= Seq(
      (1, "Ben", "ben@website.com", "secretpassword")
    )
}
```

This piece which inserts an example user

```
users ++= Seq(
  (1, "Ben", "ben@website.com", "secretpassword")
)
```

Works great for one row but I'd like to have a file with a dozen sample rows for each table (about 10 tables in total).  I can keep adding lines like this to my withSession block but as I am new to scala I confused as to how I could break this logic into a seperate piece of code/source file.

I tried making an object in another file called "TestDataBuilder"

```
object TestDataBuilder {

  import Tables._
  import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._

  users ++= Seq(
    (1, "Ben St. Pierre", "benstpierre@gmail.com", "secretpassword")
  )
}
```

Then just called TestDataBuilder inside my withSession block like so:

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult, StaticQuery => Q}

Database.forURL("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gopher_dev",
  driver = "org.postgresql.Driver",
  user = "unodishuser",
  password = "unodishpass"
) withSession {
  implicit session =>

  //drop and recreate public schema
  Q.updateNA("drop schema public cascade").execute
  Q.updateNA("create schema public").execute

  import Tables._
  //Make the tables
  (users.ddl ++ sessionData.ddl).create

  TestDataBuilder
}
```

Then I get this error:

```
[error] /usr/local/code/gofur/src/main/scala/com/lightningstrikesolutions/scala/db/TestDataBuilder.scala:11: could not find implicit value for parameter session: scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend#SessionDef
[error]   users ++= Seq(
[error]         ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 13-Aug-2014 6:11:17 PM
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need (unfortunately) to pass the session around, there's at the moment no way around it, what I usually do is avoiding using singleton and passing the session as a class parameter:

```
Database.forURL( ... ) withSession {
  implicit session =>
    val testBuildter = new TestDataBuilder()
    testBuilder.addUsers();
}
```

And then your test class:

```
import Tables._
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._

class TestDataBuilder(implicit s: Session) {

  def addUsers() = {
    users ++= Seq(
      (1, "Ben St. Pierre", "benstpierre@gmail.com", "secretpassword")
    )
  }
}
```

If you want to keep the singleton add a method to the object and pass the session to the method:

```
object TestDataBuilder {
  def addUsers(implicit s: Session) {
    users ++= Seq(
      (1, "Ben St. Pierre", "benstpierre@gmail.com", "secretpassword")
    )
  }
}
```

I prefer the first approach because if you were ever to add another function to the singleton you would have again to pass the session, in the first approach instead it becomes available to all the methods inside the class.